# Update bootcamp drivers

Tags: imac, driver

I have a new imac with the Radeon 580 Pro. I'm getting this error message when trying to play games in bootcamp.

[image]

Is there any way to get the new driver or am I stuck here?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the latest drivers with Boot Camp Assistant. Instructions for that [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204923).

TLDR version:

- Boot into MacOS
- Connect a USB drive and format it as MS-DOS (FAT) with MBR
- Open Boot Camp Assistant and select only the middle option (Download the latest Windows support software from Apple) or select Actions -> Download Windows Support Software from the menu bar
- Select the USB drive as the destination
- Restart in Windows
- Open the USB drive and the WindowsSupport folder
- Run setup.exe and select repair if needed